# creating a model and controller to get category list from db using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

1.models/calists.php // My model file 
Model file here i get the category list from database to the controller

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Catlists extends CI_Model
{
 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->load->database(); //load database

 }

 public function getCategories()
 {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('category',array('status'=>'Enable'));

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return array();
    }
}
}

?>
```

2.controllers/catlist.php // controller file 
Controller to get the data from model

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Catlist extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('catlists');

   }

  public function catlist()
  {
   $data['catlist'] = $this->catlists->getCategories();

   $this->load->view('home', $data);
   }
 }
```

In header am printng the categories list

```
  print_r($data['catlist']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what error you are getting here, but when you are loading model in controller, first letter should be capital.

```
$this->load->model('Catlists');
$data['catlist'] = $this->Catlists->getCategories();
```

In header you have to call

```
print_r($catlist);
```

Comment: If need to call the controller anywhere else bcoz am new to ci

Comment: From where you want to call it?

Comment: I didnt get any error empty result. Need to display in header

Comment: So there you just have to call  $catlist, like this:  print_r($catlist);

Comment: i created a view file and print the $catlist and include the view file in header get same empty

Comment: first try to print it in controller for testing and make sure you have values in database

Comment: I tried to print in controller and also in model no result. but i gave the same query in header  get the results

Comment: How you added view file in header??

Comment: In controller you have to print $data['catlist'].

Comment: yes in controller print_r($data['catlist']) then in model $this->db->select('*');
  $result = $this->db->get('category')->result_array();
  print_r($result); No result empty page

Comment: And you said that in header you are getting result

Comment: Try $query = $this->db->get('category');  $result = $query->result(); print_r($result); in model

Comment: if i place the query u had given in header i get the result

Comment: Which version of CI are you using 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: am using 2.1.3 codeigniter is there any version problem

Comment: You are passing data to header through controller, right??

Answer (score 0):

The file name must match the class name.

**For example**

if your class is this:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Your file will be this:

```
application/models/User_model.php
```

Here in you case your model name is

```
models/Calists.php
```

So your model file be

**Model Calists.php**

```
class Calists extends CI_Model {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
       public function getCategories()
        {
          $query = $this->db->get_where('category',array('status'=>'Enable'));

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
          return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
        }
        }
```

And you call this model file in you controller like this

**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('calists');

   }
```

CodeIgniter [anatomy of model](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model).

Comment: can you please check this answer!!